# for loop in nodejs using q library

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

The following are the functions I have

```
function start(){
 var deferred = Q.defer();
  for(var i=0; i < 3; i++){
    second()
      .then(third)
      .then(fourth)
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}

function second(){
//does an http request
// returns promise
}

function third(){
//does an http request
// returns promise
}

function fourth(){
//takes the response of second and third function
//and compares the response
//returns promise
}
```

Here is the sequence of operations when the file is run:

```
second function
second function
third function
third function 
fourth function
fourth function
```

(I know why this is happening, its due to the I/O request in second and third function)

The sequence of operations I want

```
second function
third function
fourth function
second function
third function
fourth function
```

How do I accomplish this in nodejs?

Here is a follow up to the above question: 
how to pass values to the functions in the .then(funcCall(value)) so that when the 
function is actually called it also get a value which it can work on.

Comment: Does your for loop have a special significance? Is it a pseudo-code for something, perhaps an array?

Answer (score 3):

You're halfway there, you just need to chain properly:

```js
function start() {
  var deferred = Promise.resolve();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    deferred = deferred.then(second)
      .then(third)
      .then(fourth)
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}

function second() {
  return new Promise(function(r) {
    console.log('second');
    setTimeout(r, 100);
  });
}

function third() {
  return new Promise(function(r) {
    console.log('third');
    setTimeout(r, 100);
  });
}

function fourth() {
  return new Promise(function(r) {
    console.log('fourth')
    setTimeout(r, 100);
  });
}
start();
```

Replace `Promise` with `Q`.

Comment: it directly goes to the last iteration :  here is what I get when I try to run, my original code is a little different than the other above. 

iteration: 0

iteration: 1

iteration: 2

iteration: 3

fourth function

fourth function

fourth function

Comment: i get 'second, third, fourth, second, third, fourth, second, third, fourth'. You did add `deferred = defer...` at the beginning of the loop, right?

Comment: yes, I am probably thinking its because the second third and fourth does not have a I/O operation in the example. where as the example I have do..  

not sure whats wrong, I will check. probably something wrong in the return promise.

anyways thanks helps.